# FTP from mounted CIFS - Download never ends (continues after 100%)

Tags: ftp, samba, server-message-block, cifs

I have the following situation: I have two servers, one sharing files over CIFS, the other shares files by FTP. The FTP-Server has the CIFS Share mounted, and FTP users can download from this mount.

The Problem: When an FTP User downloads a "big" file (about 800MB) from the CIFS mount the download never stops and continues after reaching 100%. If the big file is located locally (not mounted via CIFS) everything works fine. Small files (1MB) work fine.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

CIFS is mounted with `fstab`: `//192.172.11.1/share   /mnt/share          cifs    _netdev,noperm,auto,user=user,pass=password`

I also tried following options, but found no resolution: forcedirectio, llock, lfs, serverino, nobrl

FTP-Server is running on SLES 11.0, cifs-utils-4.6-6.1, proftpd-1.3.4a-13.6
CIFS server runs samba-3.6.4-100.1

Comment: nobody has an idea?

Comment: any hint would be appreciated...

Comment: have you solved the problem? I've the problem too